# Is there a quick way to extract part of list from a list of object?

Tags: java

Say, I have a List students;

Person is defined like the following

```
class Person {
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

After getting the students, is the a qucik way to get a list of ids as used, in the form List ids.

Comment: Other than looping through this whole list and populating another list with the IDs, I really cannot see any other optimal option (in Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava has Lists.transform function available. You pass in the list you want to transform and return elements associated to the list.

```
List<Person> people = ...;

List<String> ids = Lists.transform(people, new Function<People, String>(){
     public String apply(People person){
         return person.getId();
     }    
});
```

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like a `map` function as used in other languages, which build up a new list extracting just the IDs, then no, that's not directly feasible (unless by using some external collection API).

You should go the most straightforward way: iterating on the list and building up a new one by selecting just the IDs.

A way to get these things, like I mentioned, is for example to use a `TransformIterator` together with a `Transformer` but these are tools that doesn't come with SDK by default as they reside in *Apache Collections* (take a look [here](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)).

Comment: check my edit.. but I guess every collection API (also Trove) has a way to do this operations

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jack said, Or you can split the id's and make a new sequence out of that and iterate through that.